# problem in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to change the default route in RoR to what i want:
consider the following example...

```
:controller/:action/:id
```

which will give you the route in the browser as:
*http://localhost:3000/controller/action/id*

now i want to change it to...

*http://localhost:3000/this-is-what-i-want/id*

we can get an alias for the controller and the action as well like...

```
resources :controller, :as => "my-custom-name"
```

and if you want to have the alias for the action, then

```
resources :controller, :path_names => { :action => 'my-custome-name-1', :action => 'my-custome-name-2' }
```

**BUT i want to change the controller and the action at once... if u noticed the above** *http://localhost:3000/this-is-what-i-want/id* **path in the question...**

need help...
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a named route.

In Rails2:

```
map.a_name 'this-is-what-i-want/:id', :controller => 'controller_name', :action => 'action_name'
```

In Rails3:

```
match 'this-is-what-i-want/:id' => 'controller_name#action_name'
```

Comment: now what if i want: map.a_name 'this-is-what-i-want/dynamic-name/:id', :controller => 'controller_name', :action => 'action_name'... how em i gona set the link for the "dynamic-name" in rails...?

Comment: Then follow the advice of Jesse Wolgamott and use rest routes

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using Rest routes, rather than controller/action

I'm going to use "balls" instead of "this-is-what-i-want"

```
resources :balls
```

Then, when you link to a ball, do `link_to(ball.name, ball`).

This will give you a link of **http://localhost:3000/balls/45**

This [rails rest cheatsheet](http://topfunky.com/clients/peepcode/REST-cheatsheet.pdf) is a good start.